# Avoid duplicates in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL version 10.3 and I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  first VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  second VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  third VARCHAR (255), 
  fourth VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL, 
  fifth VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL);
```

I want to make numerous `INSERT` and make sure there are no duplicates.
So I thought about using `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;`.

The idea is to insert the record only if the values on the columns `first | second | third | fourth | fifth` are not already present in the table.
The problem is that the `id` is incremented automatically, so each record is different and therefore the `INSERT` always takes place.

Here we see what I mean:

```
db=# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, first VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, second VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, third VARCHAR (255), fourth VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL, fifth VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
db=# \dt
           Lista delle relazioni
 Schema |  Nome   |  Tipo   | Proprietario
--------+---------+---------+--------------
 public | example | tabella | admin
(1 riga)


db=# INSERT INTO example (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 1

db=# SELECT * FROM example;
 id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth
----+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------
  1 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
(1 riga)


db=# INSERT INTO example (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) VALUES ('11', '22', '33', '44', '55') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 1
db=# SELECT * FROM example;
 id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth
----+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------
  1 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
  2 | 11    | 22     | 33    | 44     | 55
(2 righe)


db=# INSERT INTO example (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) VALUES ('111', '222', '333', '444', '555') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 1
db=# SELECT * FROM example;
 id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth
----+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------
  1 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
  2 | 11    | 22     | 33    | 44     | 55
  3 | 111   | 222    | 333   | 444    | 555
(3 righe)


db=# INSERT INTO example (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 1
db=# SELECT * FROM example;
 id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth
----+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------
  1 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
  2 | 11    | 22     | 33    | 44     | 55
  3 | 111   | 222    | 333   | 444    | 555
  4 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
(4 righe)
```

The record `(2 | 11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55)` is equal to the record `(4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5)`. They differ only for the `id`.
I would not like the record `(4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5)` to be inserted.
How can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNIQUE` CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname UNIQUE (first, second, third, fourth, fifth);
```

Answer (score 5):

This

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname UNIQUE (first, 
second, third, fourth, fifth);
```

will not work, because of nullable  column:

```
third VARCHAR (255)
```

You can check it like that:

```
INSERT INTO example(first, second, third, fourth, fifth) values('1', '2', NULL, '4', '5');
INSERT INTO example(first, second, third, fourth, fifth) values('1', '2', NULL, '4', '5)';

SELECT * FROM example;
```

output:

```
|id|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
|1|1|2|NULL|4|5|
|2|1|2|NULL|4|5|
```

You should either:

1. set not null:
   `ALTER TABLE example ALTER COLUMN third SET NOT NULL;`
2. two indexes with NULL and NOT NULL conditions:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example(first, second, fourth, fifth) WHERE third IS NULL;
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example(first, second, third, fourth, fifth) WHERE third IS NOT NULL;
   ```
3. if it `COALSCE(third,'')` ok for your case, then:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example (first, second, COALESCE(third, ''), fourth, fifth);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple insert commands, you can use a select statement and the union will distinct the values.

```
insert into example (first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
select '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
UNION
select '11', '22', '33', '44', '55'
UNION
select '111', '222', '333', '444', '555'
UNION 
select '1', '2', '3', '4', '5';
```

result:

```
 id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth 
----+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------
  5 | 111   | 222    | 333   | 444    | 555
  6 | 1     | 2      | 3     | 4      | 5
  7 | 11    | 22     | 33    | 44     | 55
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was just an example. Actually, in my application, I do not have all data together to do the INSERT together. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_example
ON example(first, second, third, fourth, fifth);
```

it also accepts null values declare not null at table creation for fields required

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that thing to avoid duplicate in postgresql:
`insert into table_name (column) SELECT your_value WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE table_name.column='{}');`

:) good luck!